# Only allowing N amount of connections in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection

I just recently started learning node.js on the side and even though I know it will allow as many connections as physically possible, I'd like to know how to limit it to a certain amount of numbers.

Say, I'm handling http requests and  when the connection rate goes up to 4 people, I don't want it to go any further so the others have to wait until a free spot is available again when someone finishes their request.

Also I'd like to know how to make the user try to reconnect 4 times before finally being told the server's too busy with 4 connections.

Comment: Keep a counter and immediately kill new connections when it's over 4?

Comment: Is it truly the best way to do it. I think it's not a problem with only 4 people but I don't know if it's the best way to keep up when there are 1000 or more requests for a bigger page

Comment: Yes, that's basically how it works. Depending on which level you kill the connection (attempt), it might be capable of "serving" more connections at a time. Still, even denying a connection is work that requires CPU cycles/memory, and when your server cannot keep up the load then you've got DOSed.

Comment: Btw, nodejs [is capable of serving multiple thousands](https://www.google.de/search?q=nodejs+concurrent+connections) of *concurrently open* connections - not even opening them will allow you to keep "up" with even more requests. (of course, not serving a request is called "being down"). See also the [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Comment: Interesting. I already did the counter in the main "app.js" , which is added by one everytime. Since I'm working with an express and a json, I have handlers for 404 and 500, but not for 200 like the really basic node js examples do. Where should I apply this counter to substract one when it's done loading the request?

Here's my pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g3Ym7Cyq

Comment: Typically whereever you call `res.status(…)`. However, I guess there's a better method, check the docs of the lower-level http handling parts whether they emit some kind of "end" event for connections.